# Please How can I make my ImageView Splash Screen fade out after Page finish loading in Android Studio Webview?

Tags: android, android-studio

Please somebody help me with <activity_main.xml> code and <MainActivity.Java> code

Comment: Please share the code so others can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.